# How to remove preselected tag in vue-multiselect

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I need a dropdown that supports tagging and can be styled easily, so I decided to implement `vue-multiselect`. It works but the problem is that I have a predefined tag in my dropdown when the page loads and I don't what that, how can I remove it? Here is how it looks now:

[image: pic1]

and here is how I want it to look:

[image: pic2]

Here is my html code:

```
<div>
   <multiselect v-model="value" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Assesors" label="name" track-by="code" :options="options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="addTag"></multiselect>
</div>
```

and here is my js:

```
data () {
    return {
     showAddUserDialog: false,

      value: [
        { name: 'Assesors', code: 'as' }
      ],
      options: [
        { name: 'Assesors', code: 'as' },
        { name: 'Finance', code: 'fi' },
        { name: 'Sales', code: 'sa' }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addTag (newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
      }
      this.options.push(tag)
      this.value.push(tag)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, by the `<multiselect>` configuration you used and the expected behavior your showed...
You have this https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0a7E.jpg to become this https://i.stack.imgur.com/mICHE.jpg

I looks like you want to load your page only showing the placeholder, but if you'd like to only show your placeholder, you shouldn't have a value in the `value` variable, as you have:

```
data () {
  return {
    showAddUserDialog: false,
    value: [
      { name: 'Assesors', code: 'as' } // <- remove this
    ],
    options: [
      { name: 'Assesors', code: 'as' },
      { name: 'Finance', code: 'fi' },
      { name: 'Sales', code: 'sa' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Because the behavior of the component is show your current tags, right?
So if this tag is the placeholder, you can add it to the `value` when the user submits the form without choosing any other tag.

But if you want to have it there as the value and trickery the component to only show it as a placeholder, I suggest you to deep dive in the docs about custom templating...

Here talks about it https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-custom-option-template
And here talks about the tags slots
https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-slots

Here is an example:
[image: Edit Multiselect Tag Example]

Comment: If I remove the value array I lose the tagging functionality, I need it to display as a placeholder and to be able to add tags as well

Comment: Take a look in the example I created